# OrientDB how to move a vertex and maintain relations

Tags: orientdb

The title pretty much says all. I want to move a record in OrientDB from the 'Asset' class to a new class (that keeps the old version of the class 'Asset'). This is possible with MOVE VERTEX x to y. However this creates a new @RID for the node and I don't want to update all relations of the old RID to the new @RID, because this is too expensive.
Is there a solution for this?
Any help is greatly appreciated, if you need more info, please do ask.

Answer (score 0):

`MOVE VERTEX` takes care of updating all the edges to the new @RID.

Comment: Thanks, is there an equivalent method in the Java API?

Comment: I retried and in 2.0.5, it does not update all the edges; they stay all the same (referencing the old @RID). Maybe it is broken?

Comment: Please use 2.0.6 where this problem has been fixed